# Android Video Image intent return value

Tags: java, android, image, video, android-intent

I have one intent that should allow users to pick either a picture or a video from the gallery. The problem is that I cant find other method than checking the extension type to know the file type and display it in one way or another

```
public void pickMedia(View View) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/* audio/* video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {

           if (intent type == video)
                  A;

           if (intent type == audio)
                  B;

           if (intent type == image)
                  C;


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: are you calling the native gallery?  the [data] returned should be the selected , you should be able to get the file from that and determine its type

Comment: Yes I can access the file and check the extension. But I would like to be able to access the Type (e.g. "image7jpg"). To make a robust detection...

Answer (score 0):

i usually create a method similar to this:

```
public static File getFileFromUri(Uri uri, Activity activity){
        File f = null;

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getString(column_index)!=null){
            f = new File(cursor.getString(column_index));
        }else{

            InputStream is =null;
            try {
                is = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                f= stream2file(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
```

and :

```
public static String getMimeType(String url)
{
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

in your onActivityResult you can get the file chosen like so:

```
        Uri fileUri = data.getData();

        File f = getFileFromUri(fileUri, this);
        String filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        String type = getMimeType(filePath);
```